# Use a column in a Pandas dataframe to search and update a column in a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have an excel file that I want to use to update another larger excel file.
Both spreadsheets have a serial number column and I want to use the values in the serial number col from spreadsheet A to search for the serial number in spreadsheet B and then update some other values on that row whenever there is a match.

I've put both the spreadsheets into separate dataframes (dfA and dfB) and I was trying to use dfA to search and update dfB with a merge but can't quite figure it out. I'm wondering if a merge is the best way to do this? And if it is how can I do it with a merge? or what is the best way to do it?

Here's a sample of the data:

```
dfA: name serialNum status
     test1   1234   deployed
     test2   4321   retired
     test3   1111   inventory

dfB: name serialNum status
     test1   1234   NA
     test2   4321   NA
     test3   1111   NA
```

Basically I have a very large spreadsheet and I need to update the status with another spreadsheet

Comment: Update your post with a sample of `dfA` and `dfB`. Do you read [**Pandas Merging 101**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/15239951)?

Comment: I've added a sample of my data and I have not read that but will, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to update the status from dfA to dfB.

Input data:

```
>>> dfA
    name  serialNum     status
0  test1       1234   deployed
1  test2       4321    retired
2  test3       1111  inventory

>>> dfB
    name  serialNum  status
0  test1       1234     NaN
1  test2       4321     NaN
2  test3       1111     NaN
```

```
dfB['status'] = dfA.merge(dfB[['name', 'serialNum']],
                          on=['name', 'serialNum'],
                          how='right')['status']
```

The really important parameter here is `how` the merge is performed.

Output

```
>>> dfB
    name  serialNum     status
0  test1       1234   deployed
1  test2       4321    retired
2  test3       1111  inventory
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed